# How to change the graphics color for different objects in X11 graphics programming?

Tags: c, unix, graphics, colors, x11

I wanted to put different color for different objects I was drawing on **X11** graphics window.

**Example :** This is the generalized code we use to specify the color of the window display and hence the objects drawn on it.
`XAllocNamedColor(display, DefaultColormap(display, screen),"red", &color,&dummy);`

In the code shown below, both the straight line and rectangle are displayed in red color. Is there any way to display line in red and rectangle in blue color? What changes do I need to make in the code?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <X11/Xlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "time.h"
#include "sys/time.h"


 Display *display;
 Window  window;
 XSetWindowAttributes attributes;
 XGCValues gr_values;
 XFontStruct *fontinfo;
 GC gr_context;
 Visual *visual;
 int depth;
 int screen;
 XEvent event;
 XColor    color, dummy;

 main (argc, argv)
 char   *argv[];
 int     argc;
 { 


 display = XOpenDisplay(NULL);
 screen = DefaultScreen(display);
 visual = DefaultVisual(display,screen);
 depth  = DefaultDepth(display,screen);
 attributes.background_pixel = XWhitePixel(display,screen);

 window = XCreateWindow( display,XRootWindow(display,screen),
                        0, 0, 1250, 1200, 5, depth,  InputOutput,
                        visual ,CWBackPixel, &attributes);
 XSelectInput(display,window,ExposureMask | KeyPressMask) ;
 fontinfo = XLoadQueryFont(display,"6x10");

 XAllocNamedColor(display, DefaultColormap(display, screen),"red",
                  &color,&dummy);

 gr_values.font = fontinfo->fid;
 gr_values.foreground = color.pixel;


 gr_context=XCreateGC(display,window,GCFont+GCForeground, &gr_values);


 XFlush(display);
 XMapWindow(display,window);
 XFlush(display);

 while(1){
    XNextEvent(display,&event);

    switch(event.type){
    case Expose:

        XDrawLine(display,window,gr_context,800,800, 400, 450);

        XDrawRectangle(display,window,gr_context,i+10,j+10, 200, 150);

         break;

    case KeyPress: 
         XCloseDisplay(display); 
         exit(0);

     }
   }
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

In X11, you would add the color to the graphic context (GC), passed as a parameter to XDrawLine, etc.  Your program probably calls XCreateGC to create a graphic context.  You would set the foreground and/or background colors in that by OR'ing to its mask GCForeground and/or GCBackground, and copying the `Pixel` value obtained from `XAllocNamedColor` (in the `XColor` value) to the XGCValues's foreground/background structure members when creating the GC.

The `XColor` value has an R/G/B breakdown of the color (answering the followup question).  You can use [`XAllocColor`](https://tronche.com/gui/x/xlib/color/XAllocColor.html) to convert an R/G/B value to a Pixel value (see for example *[Read Only Colorcells: An easy Example](http://www-h.eng.cam.ac.uk/help/tpl/graphics/X/X11R5/node28.html)*).

Comment: Hi Thomas, Thanks. I have put the code in the question as well. As you see, both the structures are displayed in red color. What changes should I made into the code to display the straight line in red and rectangle in blue let's say?

Comment: You can either update the graphic context using `XChangeGC`, or make two -- one for each color.  Keep in mind that changes to a GC are done with calls to the X server (and the X server can cache a "few" GC's).

Comment: Thanks. Well, I couldn't follow your earlier answer to my follow up question.  I was saying if I need to draw points let's say using XDrawPoint(), I am just giving input the pixel coordinates. However, if I want to print points each with a specific pixel value, i.e. R, G, B, how to write the code for that particular section, could you please give me a hint?